# How to search specific word in csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

df:

```
   first     last                   email
0  Corey  Schafer  CoreMSchafer@gmail.com
1   Jane      Doe       JaneDoe@gmail.com
2   John      Doe       JohnDoe@gmail.com
```

From a big CSV file, how can I find a specific word like John, without knowing on what column or row he is? If there are several names with John, can I get all the info in the row or column where the names are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search an entire DataFrame for a given value without knowing which column that value will be in, we can use `.applymap()` in conjunction with `.any(axis=1)`:

```py
search_str = 'John'
search = df[df.applymap(lambda x: x == search_str).any(axis=1)]
```

`search` will be a view of your original `df` with only the rows where *any* column value is `'John'`.

Comment: Thank you very much my good man. It done the job

Answer (score 1):

That's the way to do i believe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df[df['first'].str.contains('John')] # returns all rows where John in the column 'first'
df[df['first'].str.contains('John')].index.tolist() # get the index of the rows
```

The `contains` method is case sensitive, to make it case insensitive you can do something like that:

```
df["first"].str.contains("John", case=False)
```

To find in a header column (like the first row)

```
df.columns.get_loc("first")  # Output : 0 (the column index)
```

To find in a specific column

```
df["first"].str.contains("John").any()  # Output : True
```

To find in a specific row

```
df.loc[0].str.contains("John").any()  # Output : True
```

If you want to get only row index

```
df[df["first"] == "John"].index[0]
```

Comment: big thanks Faisal The Mandalorian :D , and how can you do the same question when you don't have header (first, last, email). When you have just John Doe JohnDoe@gmail.com? Like when you get raw data, and don't have categories

Comment: Hey, check the updated answer now. Hope that will help.

Comment: once again, thx my friend. we are getting closer....
how to find a specific row that will say John is on row eg.665504, and not true or false check for the name in the database. because I don't know what df.loc[?] is he if  I want to do a True or False check

Comment: You can do this , `df[df["first"] == "John"].index[0]`